# How can I import mapbox-gl-native project into Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I want to run [Mapbox-GL-AndroidSDk-TestApp](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/android) in Mapbox-gl-native project, but when I import into Android Studio, it doesn't work. This is the Log:

> start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.testapp/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.testapp.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error
>   inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32:
>   Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mapbox-gl
>   from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.testapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.testapp-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

Comment: You first need to compile the native libraries, this is done by calling `make android` in the root directory of the project. Check out the install instructions mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To successfully compile the test app i'd suggest you check out both [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/INSTALL.md) install guide as well as this [one](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/INSTALL_OSX.md). I'm assuming you are building on OS X but theres also a guide for Linux. Let me know if you get any errors and I'll gladly help you out.

Comment: Hey Kevin, I hope my answer helped you solve the issues you were having and if it did work, please mark my answer correct so others that might come across the same question can benefit.